# In BreezseSharp how do I add the OAuth Token to the header of the Query?

Tags: breeze-sharp

I am trying to figure out how to add the OAuth Token to a Breeze-Sharp request. I am using Microsoft WebAPI and I want to use the OAuth token from OWIN to authorize all my query requests. I am not seeing where or how to change the request headers. I see that you can add parameters to a query using WithParameter but I am not seeing where I can change the header.
I am looking for something like this:

```
var query = new EntityQuery<TodoItem>().[AddHeader("Authorization","Bearer wkjksdjf...."];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the authorization header to HttpClient used by EntityManager.

eq.

```
this.entityManager.DataService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthenticationSetup.Bearer, authenticationHeader);
```